# Cloud Functions for Firebase iterate through a child node

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just started to use firebase Functions and I am new to the node.js environment, can somebody tell how to iterate through a child node and get the child values.

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase allow for quite a broad [set of use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases). Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is unlikely that we'll be able to answer better than what the documentation already does.

Answer (score 7):

see this example:

```
  const parentRef = admin.database().ref("path");
  return parentRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const updates = {};
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        updates[child.key] = null;
      });
      return parentRef.update(updates);
  });
```

Comment: This code will simply remove all the data from my path. So why would i want that?

Comment: It's just an example of how to iterate through a child node and get the child values

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked through the [Cloud Functions for Firebase Samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)?  They contain many helpful examples of common operations.  The code in [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/limit-children/functions/index.js#L27-L39) shows some of what you are looking for.