# Firebase Cloud Functions - snapshot.forEach(...).then is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My db layout is:

```
@posts
   @postId_abc
     -total_score: ... // will update from cloud function
     -score_count: ... // will update from cloud function

@scores
   @postId_abc
      -uid_1: 10
      -uid_2: 20
      _uid_3: 50
```

Whenever a user sets a score I want to use a `cloud function` to add up all of the scores from the **scores** ref and set them to the `total_score` property on that particular post. When I try the following code below I get errors:

`FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: snapshot.forEach(...).then is not a functio` and `Exception from a finished function: TypeError: snapshot.forEach(...).then is not a function`

It seems my `snapshot.forEach((child) => { ... }).then(() => {` isn't working but the `scoreCountProperty.set(...)` does increment.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateScore = functions.https.onCall((data, response) => {

    const postId = data.postId;

    const postsRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId);
    const scoreCountProperty = admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId + '/' + 'score_count');

    var totalScore = 0.0;

    admin.database().ref('scores').child(postId).once('value', snapshot => {

    if (snapshot.exists()) {

        snapshot.forEach((child) => {

            totalScore += child.val()

        })
        .then(() => { 
                
            console.log('totalScore: ', totalScore);

            return postsRef.set({ "total_score": totalScore });       
        })
        .then(() => { 
                
            return scoreCountProperty.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));                
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('ERROR - updateScore Failed: ', error);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `Snapshot.forEach()` doesn't return an object on which you can call `then()`. In fact, I'm pretty sure it returns nothing at all.

But you don't need a `then()` anyway, since `Snapshot.forEach()` is not an synchronous operation.

So this should be what you want:

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    totalScore += child.val()
})
console.log('totalScore: ', totalScore);

return postsRef.set({ "total_score": totalScore }).then(() => { 
    return scoreCountProperty.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));                
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR - updateScore Failed: ', error);
});
```